# How can it can be countable intersection?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

How  can i prove that  irrational number $( \mathbb{Q}^c)$  are countable intersection of dense open subsets of $\mathbb{R} ?$

My thinking : i know that  irrational number $(\mathbb{Q}^c)$ are  uncountable. My question is that  How can it can be   countable intersection  ?

Comment: Try to write it as intersection of some $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{c\}$ for suitable $c$?

Comment: @Mindlack im not getting   can elaborate more

Comment: By deMorgan, $\Bbb Q^\complement=\left( \bigcup_{a\in\Bbb Q}\{a\}\right)^\complement = \bigcap_{a\in\Bbb Q} \{a\}^\complement$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sir $\bigcap_{a\in\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R\setminus\{a\})= \emptyset$ Then u   mean    $ \emptyset$ is countable ????

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 's suggestion, in words. You can exclude any single rational number from a dense open set. The countable intersection of those sets will exclude all the rationals, and nothing else.

Comment: $\cap_{a\in \Bbb Q}(\Bbb R\setminus \{a\})=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$...Not $\emptyset$.... For any $A,B$ we have  $\cap_{a\in A}(B\setminus \{a\})=B\setminus A.$

Comment: BTW countable means "finite or countably infinite". This way, uncountable and "not countable" mean the same thing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  thanks u sir